# UIColor Color with RGB never gets the right color

Tags: ios, uicolor

i am trying to learn iOS developing, but i using 
`+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha`

I always not getting the right number, it always like something missing..

Please help..

here is my code:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:65/255 green:62/255 blue:125/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.f green:62/255.f blue:125/255.f alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

easy...

you simply need to add .0 at the end of each number, like this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:125.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

since they need Float value instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

Use this and add .0f after each parameter

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:62.0f/255.0f blue:125.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```